# icCube Table sort by user

Tags: iccube-reporting

In icCube 5 each table could be sorted by the user by clicking on the title of a column.
This functionality doesn't seem to be automatic any more.
Is it possible for us to activate that somehow? We couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: Did you try using Google Viz Table ? i think the pivot table was never 'sortable'

Comment: We don't use Google Tables in icCube 6, since there are massive performance problems and you suggested, we should use the icCube Table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Version 7.0.1 this feature is implemented for icCube Pivot Tables. Thank you for that :)